# Theano error: no matching function for call to ‘batch_gemm<float>

Tags: python, compiler-errors, ipython, jupyter, theano

I'm trying to launch some Python projects which I need for my bachelor thesis and they use theano.

The problem is, that one of the cell compiles these functions and fails with following compiler error: https://pastebin.com/TunvSwWU

That's the piece of code which causes that:

```
params_to_optimize  = [W_mean,U_mean,b_mean,softmax_W_mean,softmax_b_mean,h0_mean, var_log_sigma]
train_fn = theano.function([X_tensor1, X_tensor2, Mask_matrix1, Mask_matrix2,  Y_vector], cost, updates=lasagne_adagrad(cost, params_to_optimize, learning_rate=lr), on_unused_input='ignore' )
predict_fn = theano.function([X_tensor1, X_tensor2, Mask_matrix1, Mask_matrix2], output, on_unused_input='ignore')
```

The strangest thing is that in other notebook I have this code and it compiles just fine:

```
train_fn = theano.function([X_tensor1, X_tensor2, Mask_matrix1, Mask_matrix2,  Y_vector], cost, updates=lasagne_adagrad(cost, [W,U,h0,b,softmax_W,softmax_b], learning_rate=lr), on_unused_input='ignore' )
predict_fn = theano.function([X_tensor1, X_tensor2, Mask_matrix1, Mask_matrix2], output, on_unused_input='ignore')
```

I'm not really experienced theano user and right now just try to run this code before digging into it. What can be the problem?

Update:
It may have some problems with cost function which is this in compile-error case:

```
softmax_cost = -T.sum(T.log(output)[T.arange(Y_vector.shape[0]), Y_vector])*X_train1.shape[0]/X_tensor1.shape[0]
all_param_mean = [W_mean.flatten(),U_mean.flatten(), h0_mean.flatten(), b_mean.flatten(),softmax_W_mean.flatten(),softmax_b_mean.flatten()]
all_param_tensor = T.concatenate(all_param_mean)
first_part = T.exp(2*var_log_sigma)/T.exp(2*prior_log_sigma)
second_part = T.dot(prior_mu- all_param_tensor,(prior_mu-all_param_tensor).T)/T.exp(2*prior_log_sigma)
third_part = -np.sum([len(i.eval()) for i in all_param_mean])
fourth_part = 2*prior_log_sigma - 2*var_log_sigma 
KLD = 0.5* (first_part + second_part + third_part + fourth_part)
cost = softmax_cost + KLD
```

And this in compiling case:

```
softmax_cost = -T.mean(T.log(output)[T.arange(Y_vector.shape[0]), Y_vector])
all_params = T.concatenate([W.flatten(), U.flatten(), b, h0, softmax_W.flatten(), softmax_b])
l2_cost = lambda2*(all_params**2).sum()
cost = softmax_cost + l2_cost
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing all the dependencies via Conda solves it.